# Как привязать декоративны элемент с помощью before?

Tags: html, css

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как реализовать такой декоративный элемент?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пробую добавить его через `before`, но почему-то не выходит. Скажите пожалуйста, в чём заключается проблема.

```css
.test h2 {
  position: relative;
  font-size: 37px;
}

.test h2::before {
  content: '';
  width: 200px;
  height: 10px;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="test">
  <h2>Тест</h2>
</div>
```

Comment: дай ему top0 bottom -2

Comment: к сожалению не помогло(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
.test {
  position: relative;
  font-size: 37px;
}

.test h2::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 120px;
  height: 5px;
  background: red;
  bottom: -5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="test">
  <h2>Тест</h2>
</div>
```

Comment: спасибо большое

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы этот пустой псевдоэлемент стал видимым, ему необходимо задать либо `display:block`, либо `position:absolute`.

В варианте без абсолютного позиционирования лучше заменить `::before` на `::after`

```css
.test h2 {
  position: relative;
  font-size: 37px;
}

.test h2::after {
  content: '';
  width: 200px;
  height: 10px;
  background: red;
  display:block;
}
```

```html
<div class="test">
  <h2>Тест</h2>
</div>
```

Comment: спасибо! ваш ответ помог разобраться. ломал голову несколько часов